# Detect region from edges

Tags: python, opencv

I've got a micrograph showing a number of grains that have a rather clear boundary. I've used OpenCV-Python to detect these boundaries (with a Canny filter), and I think it was rather successful in its attempt, see figure. I would like to identify and mark the individual regions bounded by the detected edges, and then get the area (number of pixels) contained those regions. My apologies if the question was asked (and answered) before, but I could not find any satisfying answers yet.

Thanks in advance

Original image
[image: Original image]
Original image overlain by the detected edges
[image: Original image overlain by edges]

Comment: can you add original image and another image where you mark all pixels that you want to count in a green color or sth?

Comment: It seems the perfect application for [this](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) tutorial

Comment: @Miki From what I understand from the tutorial, one applies the watershed method to objects that have good contrast with the background. As you can see in my images, only the boundaries have contrast, but the grains themselves have the same intensity as the background, thus watershed does not work. How would you proceed to apply the tutorial contents to this problem?

Comment: @MPA, sorry, I did't saw the original image before. You're right, that's not trivial.

Comment: sorry, still dont know which pixels you want to count... do you know what is inside and what is outside of the contour? If yes, just use cv::findContours and count the contour pixels. But it looks like contours aren't closed, so maybe first try a close-operation (cv::dilate followed by a cv::erode) on the edges and extract contours afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If the grain makes no difference in the color (maybe on the raw data rather than a compressed format), you may wanna use the Becke line to distinguish inside and outside. The borders of your grain appear dark on the inside and white on the outside. But this depends also on the focus of the microscope. [See here](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/petrology/Tsecplp.htm).

In the case that your grains do not enclose totally a background spot you can use a [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) approach.